# Which Star Wars comics does this page (featuring Darth Vader and Emperor Palpatine by Mark Mckenna) come from?

Tags: star-wars, comics, darth-vader, object-identification, dark-horse-comics

Which Star Wars comics does this page (featuring Darth Vader and Emperor Palpatine by Mark Mckenna) come from?

[image]

Comment: https://www.comicartfans.com/gallerypiece.asp?piece=1713185

Comment: Although I wonder if that's you in the comments, asking where it's from. :-D

Comment: Given that the Empire appears to be visiting Earth, I suspect this is just a sketch that hasn't appeared in any official Star Wars comic.

Comment: Well I got this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMJNp.jpg

Comment: Don't forget you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmakr by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

Well I got this - [TARGET EARTH by Mark Mckenna](https://makersplace.com/product/target-earth-1-of-1-40904/)

> Mark's licensed work on STAR WARS : PURGE and The Old Republic continue to be collected in Marvel Comics trade paperbacks. Mark has also had a long standing run on Marvel's EXILES having been credited with 40 issues of ink work.
>
> Description
>
> On their path of planetary domination, two of the most devious and dark characters in science fiction history come across Planet Earth. They've been researching Earth and its problems and deem it unworthy to conquer.
>
> This was a compelling piece to develop. The year 2020 has been unkind to us here on planet Earth. I came up with the concept of villainess characters from a galaxy far far away working their way through their own galaxy eventually continuing on to our Solar System. Once they come across Earth, they determine that our planet is in bad shape and decide to move along.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a link to whichever page you copied and pasted that text from?

Comment: https://makersplace.com/product/target-earth-1-of-1-40904/

Comment: Nice find! Wouldn't have guessed it would be an NFT.